# read nested json object using loop

Tags: java, json, object, json-simple

I have been searching from a long time and no solutions is working for me.
I have to retrieve the values from the json object using some loop , and number of nested values is random these can be 1 or may be 10.
json looks like this :

```
{
   "keyInfo":[
      {
         "name":"ipek",
         "key":"1221"
      },
      {
         "name":"ipek",
         "key":"1221"
      }
   ],
   "terminalInfo":{
      "dateExp":"2-2-2",
      "deviceId":"1222",
      "tid":"122"
   }
}
```

I have tried alot of solutions one of them is this :

```
 JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(jsonString);
 JSONObject jsonChildObject = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("keyInfo");
 Iterator iterator  = jsonChildObject.keys();
 String key = null;
 while(iterator.hasNext()){
     key = (String)iterator.next();
     System.out.println("inval value: "
         + ((JSONObject)jsonChildObject.get(key)).get("inval"));
 }
```

but none of them is working for me please help.
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: The json example you provided does not contain the key "files". Is the json you provided the value for the "files" key and `jsonString` is bigger than what you provided?

Comment: it was a mistake i have edited it, it is basically not file ,it is keyInfo.

Comment: Have you considered using an object mapper like Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an array as a map. `jsonChildObject` is actually an `JSONArray`. It does not have keys; for instance you can have the same `{"name":"ipek","key":"1221"}` multiple times. If you know that the `key` is unique among items in this array, you can try and build a HashMap out of it if you need, but the structure you have is definitely an array.